# fixing a mobile menu and logo as header for smaller screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, responsive

I have a side navigation menu for bigger screens in this file. I want to create a navigation bar for mobile phones and smaller screens below `1024px` width. I have tried making the mobile navbar hidden for bigger screens and it just acts up. I need some here is a link to my page

I will want it to look like this [image: The way I want the mobile version to look.]
I got the inspiration of the page from [link](http://duruthemes.com/demo/html/pwe/multipage/index.html) and they were able to make it responsive.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("home-page-slides");
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var slideLength = slides.length;

  // Fade in the slide
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (slideIndex == slideLength) {
      slideIndex = 0;
    }
    slides[slideIndex].classList.add("fadeIn");
  }, 10);

  //Fade out the SLide
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (slideIndex == slideLength) {
      slideIndex = 0;
    }
    slides[slideIndex].classList.remove("fadeIn");
  }, 3980);

  slideIndex++;
  setTimeout(showSlides, 4000);
}
```

```css
/*----------------------------------------------------
    @Navigation menu
-----------------------------------------------------*/

.logo {
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.navbar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 9px;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.navbarFooter {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.divider {
  width: 16%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.navFContent {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}


/*----------------------------------------------------
    @Home Page
    -----------------------------------------------------*/

.slideshow-container,
.main {
  width: calc(100%-300px);
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.desc-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  margin-left: 315px;
}

.desc {
  margin: auto;
  width: 450px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

.home-page-slides {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.home-page {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.home-page-slides img {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: top;
}
```

```html
<base href="https://happy-kepler-414939.netlify.app/" /> <!-- insert by SO editor -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;1,200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="" href="logos/favicon2.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animations.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/event.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/restaurant.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/memorial.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/venue.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/portfolio.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">

<div class="navbar whitebg" id="navbar">
  <div id="banner" class="mobile-banner">
    <div class="mobile-logo"></div>
    <div id="mobile" class="mobile-menu">
      <a onClick="openNav()">
        <div class="open">
          <div id="burger" class="burger">
            <div class="bun01"></div>
            <div class="patty"></div>
            <div class="bun02"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main-nav">
    <nav class="menu centertext fontlight">
      <ul>
        <img class="logo" src="logos/mainLogo.png" alt="">
        <li><a class="blacktxt" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a class="blacktxt" href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a class="blacktxt" href="html/about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a class="blacktxt" href="#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
        <li><a class="blacktxt" href="html/portfolio.html">OUR PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a class="blacktxt" href="html/venue.html">EXCLUSIVE VENUES</a></li>
        <li><a class="blacktxt" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>

    </nav>

    <div class="navbarFooter blacktxt fontlight">
      <div class="divider"></div>

      <div class="navFContent">
        <p>
          +1 (646) 580-7740
        </p>
        <p>
          info@hillandboyd.com
        </p>
        <p>
          New York, USA.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- HOME PAGE CONTENT-->
<section id="home-page">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="home-page">

      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="home-page-slides">
          <img src="Images/eventbg1.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="desc-container">
            <div class="desc p30 whitebg">
              <h6 class="goldtxt f30">Luxury Events</h6>
              <h2 class="blacktxt f18">WE CREATE BEAUTIFUL EVENTS</h2>
              <p class="greytxt f15 fontlight">Join us for a “No Question too Small, Large or Outrageous” Chat about All things Bridal! This is your chance to have two industry experts answer your queries on any topic that is keeping you up at night.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="home-page-slides">
          <img src="Images/restaurantbg1.jpg" style="width:100%"/>
          <div class="desc-container">
            <div class="desc p30 whitebg">
              <h6 class="goldtxt f30">Creating Impact</h6>
              <h2 class="blacktxt f18"> STRATEGY AND SALES</h2>
              <p class="greytxt f15"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="home-page-slides">
          <img src="Images/memorialbg1.jpg" style="width:100%"/>
          <div class="desc-container">
            <div class="desc p30 whitebg">
              <h6 class="goldtxt f30">Lasting Memories</h6>
              <h2 class="blacktxt f18">SERVING WITH LOVE</h2>
              <p class="greytxt f15"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: DOes the template you are using support hamburger menus?

Comment: As far as I can telll, the CSS doesn't seem to be written with responsiveness in mind. You'll have to make a mobile friendly CSS and then combine it with the desktop version with media queries.

Comment: @SwimmerF it was actually if you go to [link](http://duruthemes.com/demo/html/pwe/multipage/index.html) they used the exact same style and were able to make it responsive. I got the screen shot from their mobile version.

Comment: @mplungjan yes it does.

Comment: @Debs The demo site you provided is using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), a popular CSS and JS library. You might want to check that out.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the navigation panel & make the site responsive in mobile view use media query in css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 736px) { /* css property for phone */ }
```

To animate and view side navigation
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp

Comment: How do I successfully hide the big screen navigation without it affecting the height and spacing of the big screen menu. Animating it is not the issue but skillful  removing the navigation menu and I do not want it to be the exact same way with the page, I want a top nav

Comment: @Debs adding .navbar{display:block;} to media query will remove the navigation bar for you in phone view

Comment: It is beyond that to do the work Paul.if you take time out to check out the code and try to implement that you'll see what I mean. Thanks for trying though

Comment: @Debs in the site you mentioned above they have used bootstrap, sticky-kit, jquery, modenizer and other js files. please check out the main.js file in the mentioned [link](http://duruthemes.com/demo/html/pwe/multipage/index.html)

Comment: What would you want me to look at in the main JS file ?